# getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im aware similar questions exist but none of those have provided me with an answer that works..

Basically I have a site with some services that inject data dynamically

In my app.component.ts I have two headers.. one when your on the home page and one for when your on any other page

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/'"></app-header>
<app-header-home *ngIf="router.url != '/'"></app-header-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  router: string;

  constructor(
    private _router: Router
  ) {
       this.router = _router.url;
  }
}
```

now I also have a service that dynamically injects the title of the header

**headerTitle.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderTitleService {
  title = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor() { }

  setTitle(title: any) {
  this.title.next(title);
  }
}
```

then In my home component for example I set the title

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderTitleService } from '../../services/headerTitle.service';
import { HeaderImageService } from '../../services/headerImage.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private headerTitleService: HeaderTitleService,
    private headerImageService: HeaderImageService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.headerTitleService.setTitle(`
    We strive to create things
    <br> that are engaging, progressive
    <br> &amp; above all
    <span class="highlight">
    <em>innovative.</em>
    </span>
  `);
 }

}
```

now basically it was all working until I put in the if statements on the two headers

now Im getting this error

`Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: ''. Current value: '
    We strive to create things
    <br> that are engaging, progressive
    <br> &amp; above all
    <span class="highlight">
    <em>innovative.</em>
    </span>
  '.`

not sure how I can fix this.. I tried setting the values in `ngAfterViewInit` but it did nothing

or does anyone know another way I could accomplish this??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You can try using a `setTimeOut` method instead and set the values
>   inside of that

```
setTimeout(this.headerTitleService.setTitle(`
    We strive to create things
    <br> that are engaging, progressive
    <br> &amp; above all
    <span class="highlight">
    <em>innovative.</em>
    </span>
`), 0);
```

note this is a work around and not a full proff solution to the problem .

To know why this error occurs in Angular change detection you need to know how the change detection works in Angular for this you can refer to this blog by [`Maxim NgWizard K`](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Just tried doing this and It still gives the same error

Comment: Then there is something else thats causing the expression changed error. It will be great of you reproduce this on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I know i fixed this in mine.

here is a great post

[everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

i have forced the change detection

```
export class AppComponent {
name = 'I am A component';
text = 'A message for the child component';

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yeah see I tried doing this in my header component but it doesnt seem to be working